# Logstash 6.8 with JDBC data ingestion rate issue

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

[image: gs]

As Shown in the picture , testing log-stash JDBC data fetch from PG , as the time pass , each chunk of data ( 100K each ) is taking more and more time. Can someone explain why the pipeline is behaving like that. The issue is the same regardless of the data fetch and page size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was the PostGres, as it brings the initial rows faster than higher rows in the table. ( with large tables )